# (Javascript) Recursive function that works on first call but not on second When Oscillating numbers

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to do iteration for oscillating number, by using **Recursion on Javascript**, but unfortunately it didn't get the expected output. The first call works but the second fail. Here is the code:

```js
let result = [];
    function oscillator(A) {
      if (result[result.length - 1] == A) {
        // base case
        return result;
      }
      let number = A;
      if (number > 0) {
        number -= 5;
        result.push(number);
      } else {
        number += 5;
        result.push(number);
      }
      return oscillator(number);
    }
    console.log(oscillator(16));
```

The Result shown is just **[ 11 ]**
When The expected output should be: **16 11 6 1 -4 1 6 11 16**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What should be changed

From that code, the base case of the recursion should be changed to:

```
if (base == 0) {
  base = A;
} else if (A == base) {
  return result;
}
```

#### Full code

```js
let result = [];
var base = 0;
var dirDown = true;
function oscillator(A) {
  // need to set the condition to check if the base case is number is reached.
  if (base == 0) {
    base = A;
  } else if (A == base) {
    return result;
  }
  
  // Push the number into result
  result.push(A);
  
  let number = A;
  if ((number > 0) && dirDown) {
    number -= 5;
  } else {
    // set dirDown to false to prevent the number keep looping in -4 and 1
    dirDown = false;
    number += 5;
  }
  
  return oscillator(number);
}
console.log(oscillator(16));
```

#### The result

If you run the snippet above, you will see this result:

```
[16, 11, 6, 1, -4, 1, 6, 11]
```

**Thank you for tidying the code**

**Added some comment in the code for explanation**

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6fp047ex/)

Comment: Amazing... Your answer has saved my life ! Wish U all the best!